# How to access server behind an acccess point router, which is behind my ISP router?

Tags: port, ip-address, router, openssh

I can successfully SSH into my server if I connect that PC directly to my ISP provided router (point 1 below), with port forwarding etc.

However I need to connect another router as an access point first, and then connect my server PC to that router(point 2 below).

Thus the connection changes from:

```
1. ISP router - LAN cable - Server PC
```

TO:

```
2. ISP router - LAN cable - access point router - LAN cable - Server PC.
```

I just plug the LAN cables in as in the second scenario above, and internet etc works on all my PC's, including the Server PC. I have tried changing IPv4 settings, port forwarding on both routers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either:

- port forward (1) from your ISP router to your AP router and port forward (2) from your AP router to your sever PC (fixed IP)
- or you inform the ISP router of the subnet created by the AP router, by adding the subnet to the ISP's routing table (if you've access to the routing table).
- Or, unless you really need the AP to act as a router, check if you can configure it as a regular switch so the whole network will be one subnet. Doing so, you can stick to your initial setup.

Comment: Thanks. Ok that was actually quite easy - to take option one you listed.